# Escaping C#, little baffled

Tags: c#

I feel stupid for asking such a question. How do I escape double quotes?

I've tried Google and it says to use \" but it don't seem to work.

```
string html = @"<a href=\"http://google.com\">Test</a>";
```

It returns

```
';' expected
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12):

One of these:

```
string html = "<a href=\"http://google.com\">Test</a>";
string html = @"<a href=""http://google.com"">Test</a>";
```

The escaping varies between the two forms. The second, with the "@" prefix, is known as a **verbatim string literal**, allows line breaks and so on, and doesn't treat the backslash as a special escaping character. It thus handles everything except the double quote without need for escaping - and the double quote is escaped by doubling it so it isn't interpreted as the end of the string literal.

Comment: Why does an extra quote need to be used in the version with the @? Is it because the @ is used for heredoc?

Comment: @James: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28VS.71%29.aspx: "The advantage of @-quoting is that escape sequences are not processed." That is why you need extra quotes instead of \.

Comment: @James - how about that "tick" then...? ;)